# DevExpress GridView conflicts with DatePicker Jquery file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress-mvc, mvcgrid

I have a DevExpress MVC GridView in my MVC View, the callbacks get frozen and shows infinite Loading Panel when i attach these two DatePicker Jquery files into my view.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/js/jquery-1.11.0.js"> </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../../GIZWSIP-FstComponent/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I tried using no conflict to true but seems it doesn't work, any idea?

Thanks

Comment: can you show all scripts that are included in the same order in which they are in your view>?

Comment: There are no other scripts only these two.

Comment: MVC standard includes jQuery and jQuery UI already, so maybe it is loaded twice?